# How to get a larger format then 640x426 using modprobe and gphoto2

Tags: ffmpeg, modprobe, v4l

I am using the following command to use my Nikon as a webcam:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback && gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

This works like a charm:

```
ffmpeg version N-49161-g50e194e6e1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0x6d15940] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x426, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
```

However the max resolution for this is `640x426` I would love to be able to use larger formats if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have rawvideo as input, you must tell ffmpeg the frame size.  Problem is, that the raw video codec data does not necessarily contain the dimensions of a frame.

So the ffmpeg part of your call could look like this:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x780 -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

I've omitted the threads parameter in order to let ffmpeg use all available threads and added `-s 1024x780` as an example for a frame size - which you can substitute to the real size of the raw stream.

More infos [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion)

Comment: The input is not rawvideo but a raw mjpeg stream. Your `-s` parameter will rescale the input. What the OP wants is to procure a larger frame from the source. This will require configuration changes in the camera and/or gphoto2 if at all possible.

Comment: Well, the ffmpeg doc distinguishes between input and output parameters. Quote: "As an input option, this is a shortcut for the video_size private option, recognized by some demuxers for which the frame size is either not stored in the file or is configurable – e.g. raw video or video grabbers." - But you are right: I've borked the command and will correct it....

Comment: Thank you both :) Interesting it says the option was not found: `Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0x663b8c0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Option video_size not found.
`
But I can also see it clearly in the documentation